# Not able to write in html file in VS Code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

When ever I make a HTML file in VS Code the screen is black and I am not able to write in it. Whereas whenever I make a file of another extension like .java or .css it works and I can type in it. Tell me what to do.

When I make a file, it says this:

[image: when i make a file it says this]

After adding .html it shows blank screen:

[image: after adding .html it shows blank screen]

But I am able to write in other extension:

[image: but i am able to write in other extension]

I removed the vim extension, but that doesn't work, and I don't know what to do.

Comment: try to create a new file in vs code then press ctrl + shift + p , search for 'Change language mode', select language 'HTML'.

Answer (score -1):

A few items --

1. Try uninstalling it and doing a clean install.
2. Submit it to Microsoft [Report a problem with the Visual Studio product or installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022)